# Add new attribute to existing hash

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am retrieving results using Mongoid, but I want to add a new attribute to each of the records returned in an instance variable using the key. How would I go about doing this?

In PHP I would do this by looping through the array and inserting it based on the key of the object. I am unable to figure out how this can be done in Ruby when I receive the message: Model ABC can't be converted into an Integer.

**Update:** I ended up adding a method in the model to achieve what I was trying to do.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I am asking simply how one would go achieving this in Ruby after researching how I would do it myself using the key returned in a loop.

Comment: Everyone has to start from somewhere. I mentioned what I am trying to solve in Ruby coming from PHP.

Comment: Without seeing your code it's difficult to help. You'd loop over the results, and add the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to point you in the right direction.

If you have an array of records and what to loop through it, use Array#each: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-each

You can write attributes easily: http://rdoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Attributes#write_attribute-instance_method

Hope that helps